# Error while trying to compile Curl library in debian wheezy

Tags: curl, compilation, debian, libcurl

I downloaded curl library using the following commands:

```
apt-get build-dep cur
apt-get source curl
cd curl-7.26.0/
./configure
make
```

After running make, an error is shown as below:

```
strdup.o: In function `Curl_memdup':
strdup.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `Curl_cmalloc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [curl] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kia/Desktop/curl/curl-7.26.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kia/Desktop/curl/curl-7.26.0/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I'm going to add the curl library to a minimized kernel which I built it before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because of a security patch they applied that wasn't entirely correct for the cmalloc stuff. I would probably still recommend that you consider downloading and building a newer version directly from the curl site instead...